# Add a number in a List<double> array

Tags: c#

I want to add a number to a
`List<double>[] distances = new List<double>[2];`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
         double distance = MyFunktionthatreturnsANumber();
         distances[i].Add(distance);
    }
}
```

But everytime I try to run this code i get this error at the first passage if the loop:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: You have declared an array of two lists of double. You never initialized the two elements of that array.

Comment: have you declared distances

Comment: For fun: `List<double>[] distances = Enumerable.Range(0,2).Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(j => MyFunktionthatreturnsANumber()).ToList()).ToArray();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring an array of `List<double>` objects, but you aren't initializing the elements of that array to an object?

```cs
List<double>[] distances = new List<double>[2];
distances[0] = new List<double>();
distances[1] = new List<double>();

# continue
```